# imagecreatefromstring source from mysql

Tags: mysql, database, string, url

I have a problem with adding image URL from database data.

```
my image path : "Item 0x75A3.jpg"
my mysql data ($itemid) : 75A3
```

I have tried :

```
$src = "Item%200x$itemid.jpg";
$stars = imagecreatefromstring($src);
imagepng($stars);
```

not print anything.

When I try to this :

```
$src = "Item 0x75A3.jpg";
$stars = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
imagepng($stars);
```

everything works fine. How do I write image path?

Comment: By using `imagecreatefromjpeg($src)`? You say that works already. What is the problem here?

Comment: i must get the url from mysql...

Comment: `$src = "Item 0x${itemid}.jpg"; $stars = imagecreatefromjpeg($src); imagepng($stars);`?